# Ansible retries option with any_errors_fatal

Tags: ansible

We have a deployment ansible playbook that deplys to a couple of servers behind a bastion server that we connect via ssh. Sporadically a server doesn't connect momentarily but a retry should work.

If I add the retries option to [ssh_connection] section will that still work or be overridden by the any_errors_fatal.

In the ansible.cfg we have the below options

```
   [defaults]
   private_key_file = <Key_location>
   remote_user = <remote_user>
   host_key_checking = False
   any_errors_fatal = True
   [ssh_connection]
   pipelining=true
   control_path = %(directory)s/%%C
   retries = 3
```

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try set the timeout value=60 and retest.
I configured timeout=60 under default section below.

```
[defaults]
private_key_file = <Key_location>
remote_user = <remote_user>
host_key_checking = False
any_errors_fatal = True
timeout=60
```